# Yum is not respecting `Requires` maximum version. How can I debug and check what yum thinks the dependency version is?

Tags: package-management, yum, rpm, dependencies, rpm-spec

I manage an RPM package and there are versions numbered like:

`my-package-1.1.1-1`, `my-package-1.1.2-1`, `my-package-1.1.3-1`, `my-package-1.2.0-0.alpha01.1`.

I'm now trying to get another package to depend on `my-package < 1.2` so that only a 1.1 version is installed. However when I install with `yum`, it will always install the latest version (`my-package-1.2.0-0.alpha01`) instead of one that satisfies the requirement.

How can I check what `yum` thinks my package's version is?

Here is the spec for the package with the requirement:

```
Name:       test
Version:    1
Release:    1
Requires: my-package < 1.2

%description
%prep
%build
%install
%files
```

I also tried `Requires: my-package < 0:1.2` with no success.

The rpm spec for `my-package` 1.2 starts with:

```
Name: my-package
Provides: my-package
Version: 1.2.0
Release: 0.alpha01.1%{?dist}
```

and for the 1.1 versions:

```
Name: my-package
Provides: my-package
Version: 1.1.3
Release: 1%{?dist}
```

Only the `Version:` line is changed to set different versions numbers. No epoch is set, so I assume it will default to `0:`.

`rpmdev-vercmp "1.2.0-0.alpha01.1" "1.2"` correctly returns `1.2.0-0.alpha01.1 > 1.2`. So I don't think the numbering is incorrect.

Weirdly: even if I set `Epoch: 200`  on my 1.2 version of `my-package` and set the `test` package to require `my-package < 10:1.2` it installs the 200:1.2.0 version.

I think the problem is that `yum` isn't correctly parsing the built `my-package.rpm`'s version. How can I check?

#### EDIT 1

Here are some diagnostics using `rpm -q`, it looks like version dependencies are correct?:

```
$ rpm -qp  --requires test-1-1.x86_64.rpm 
my-package < 1.2
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1


$ rpm -qp --provides my-package-1.1.3-1.noarch.rpm 
my-package
my-package = 1.1.3-1

$ rpm -qp --provides my-package-1.2.0-0.alpha01.1.noarch.rpm 
my-package
my-package = 1.2.0-0.alpha01.1
```

#### EDIT Reproduction steps!

I made reproduction code! Tested it on Centos7 running from home dir.
Requires `rpmdevtools` and `createrepo` to be installed.

```
#/bin/bash
echo "Name:       my-package
Provides:   my-package
Version:    \${VERSION}
Release:    \${RELEASE}
Summary:    NA
License:    NA

%description
%prep
%build
%install
%files
" | tee template.spec

echo "Name:       has-requirement
Version:    1
Release:    1
Summary:    NA
License:    NA

Requires: my-package < 1.2

%description
%prep
%build
%install
%files
" | tee has-requirement.spec

vers=("1.1.1" "1.1.2" "1.1.3" "1.2.0")


rpmdev-setuptree
for v in ${vers[@]}; do
    VERSION=$v RELEASE="1" envsubst '$${VERSION} $${RELEASE}' < template.spec > my-package.spec
    rpmbuild -ba my-package.spec
done
rpmbuild -ba has-requirement.spec

repodir="$PWD/repo"
mkdir -p $repodir
mv ./rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/my-package* $repodir
createrepo $repodir

echo "[temp]
name=temp repo
baseurl=file://$repodir
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0" | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/temp.repo

sudo yum clean all; sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum
sudo yum search my-package --show-duplicates
sudo yum localinstall --assumeno $PWD/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/has-requirement-1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of anyone else facing this problem of yum not recognising dependency versions, this is how I fixed the dependency resolution.

In my dependency package, the rpm spec header started with:

```
Name:       my-package
Provides:   my-package
Version:    1.2.0
Release:    0
```

The line `Provides: my-package` was redundant and it was confusing `yum` because it meant all versions of the package were providing `my-package`. I don't entirely know why that was causing version and epoch numbers to be ignored, but there you go.

Removing the `my-package` package name from the list of stuff it provides, made yum observe versioning requirements as expected.

I think this is probably a bug in `yum`. I haven't tested if `dnf` does the same thing.

Comment: not sure this is a bug, but I do agree that `yum` sometimes behaves strangely with `Provides` and `Obsoletes`... watch out with those :)

Answer (score 2):

you can ask `rpm` to tell you the requirement for your test package:

if it is installed:

```
rpm -q test --requires
```

if it is not installed:

```
rpm -qp /path/to/test.rpm --requires
```

that could help you out.

You error is indeed strange; are you sure the correct `test.rpm` is being installed; with the correct depencency?

Comment: You're right I'd forgotten about using `rpm --provides`, unfortunately it isn't giving me any more clues though.
I'm checking the install with `yum localinstall --assumeno` and seeing what dependencies resolve